# How to automatically delete item, left with no subitems in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Sorry for the bad title, I couldn't come up with something better :(

I have ShoppingCart Entity and Product Entity. The ShoppingCart has:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="ShoppingCart", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $products;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

and the Product has:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\ShoppingCart")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shopping_cart_id", referencedColumnName="shopping_cart_id")
 * })
 */
private $shoppingCart;
```

Now in my controller, in the action for removing products I have a check:
`if there is only one product left in the cart, delete both the cart and the product`

Is there a way from Doctrine to automatically check this and delete the cart, if there are no products left in it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is out-of-the-box support for this in Doctrine. I would implement an [event listener/subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html), listening to the postRemove event. You could inject the entity manager, do the count of the products and remove the parent shopping cart when no products are left in the cart.